# Reverse Engineering - AND 0FF

Tags: debugging, reverse, ollydbg

I do some reverse engineering stuff with simple crackme app and I'am debugging it with OllyDbg.

I'm stuck at the behavior of instruction AND with operand 0x0FF. I mean It's equivalent in C++ to 
**if(... = true)**.

So what's confusing is that:

```
    ECX = CCCCCC01
    ZF = 1
    AND ECX, 0FF
    ### After instruction
    ECX  = 00000001
    ZF = 0
    ZF - Should be active
```

I don't know why is result of ECX register 1 and ZF isn't active.

AND => 1 , 1     = 1 (Same operands)
       Otherwise = 0

Can someone explain me that?

*thankx for help*

Comment: Why do you think that ZF should be 1 ? The result of the AND is not zero, so ZF will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit-wise AND, so in binary you have

```
    1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 0000 0001
AND 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
    ----------------------------------------
    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```